# Robust page layout when re-sizing

Tags: css, html, css-float

I currently have two divs on my page that are about center-left, and they're both floated left.  My problem is that when I resize the page to make it smaller, the right div will sink under the left div, and I would prefer it to maintain it's position next the the other div.

What CSS sorcery would allow me to do this? (if any)

Comment: Can u show this in Fiddle..?

Comment: Hey SAM did checked the posted answer...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please check the following corresponding codes, it ll helps you....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #left {
                border:1px solid red;
                width:40%;
                height:auto;
                float:left;
            }
            #right {
                border:1px solid blue;
                width:40%;
                height:auto;
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="left">
            <h1>Sample 1</h1>
            <h1>Sample 1</h1>
            <h1>Sample 1</h1>
            <h1>Sample 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <h1>Sample 2</h1>
            <h1>Sample 2</h1>
            <h1>Sample 2</h1>
            <h1>Sample 2</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While developing a fluid layout, a common mistake is mixing, `%` units with `px` values.

Size of `%` is respective to available space and does not work efficiently when there are values with `px` or `em` or `...`

If you are using `%` units to size the layouts, you have to make sure, you have to `%` for everything `border`, `padding`, `margin`.

For such layout

```
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>
<div id="center">
    Center
</div>
```

CSS,

```css
#left, #center { float: left; }
#left { width: 26%; padding: 2%; }
#center { width: 66%; padding: 2%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do it without using % sizes as they are dangerous ;)

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="center">Center</div>
<br />
```

And the CSS:

```
#left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#center {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

br {
    clear: both;
}
```

All the best wishes,

[Mohammad Ali Sharpasand](http://m.a.sharpasand.com/)